# Need to add field in apex class email template - not working

Tags: apex, email, class, custom-field

```
public with sharing class CaseTriggerHandler implements ITrigger{
    List<Case_Call__c> ccList = new List<Case_Call__c>();
    List<Case> newCaseToEmail = new List<Case>();
    List<Case> escalatedCasesToEmail = new List<Case>();
    List<Case> closedCasesToEmail = new List<Case>();
    RecordType custReqRecType = new RecordType();
    RecordType retradeReqRecType = new RecordType();

// Used to store the string that will need to get added
// Into the text field 'Snippet_Information__c'
    Map<Id,String> snippetIdMap = new Map<Id,String>();

//Used to store resolution emails as Kinnser Email Messages in SF
    List<Kinnser_Email_Message__c> kemResolutions = new List<Kinnser_Email_Message__c>();


    public void bulkBefore(){
        if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
            Set<Id> parentSnippetIds = new Set<Id>();
            for(Sobject sob : Trigger.new){
                Case c = (Case)sob;
                If(c.Add_Snippet__c != NULL){
                    parentSnippetIds.add(c.Add_Snippet__c);
                }
            }

            If(parentSnippetIds.size() > 0){
                For(Snippet__c snip : [SELECT Id, Description__c FROM Snippet__c WHERE Id IN : parentSnippetIds]){
                    snippetIdMap.Put(snip.Id , snip.Description__c);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * bulkAfter
     *
     * This method is called prior to execution of an AFTER trigger. Use this to cache
     * any data required into maps prior execution of the trigger.
     */
    public void bulkAfter(){
        if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){

            for(RecordType r : [SELECT Name, Id FROM RecordType WHERE Name LIKE 'Customer Requests' OR Name LIKE 'Retrade Request']){
                If(r.Name == 'Retrade Request'){
                    retradeReqRecType = r;
                } else if(r.Name == 'Customer Requests'){
                    custReqRecType = r;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * beforeInsert
     *
     * This method is called iteratively for each record to be inserted during a BEFORE
     * trigger. Never execute any SOQL/SOSL etc in this and other iterative methods.
     */
    public void beforeInsert(SObject so){
        Case currentCase = (Case)so;

        if(currentCase.Subject != NULL){
            currentCase.Subject_Encrypted__c = currentCase.Subject;
            currentCase.Subject = NULL;
        }

        if(currentCase.Description != NULL){
            currentCase.Encrypted_Description__c = currentCase.Description;
            currentCase.Description = NULL;
        }

        // If the snippet lookup is not null, append the snippet text
        // to the snippet information textbox
        if(currentCase.Add_Snippet__c != NULL){
            String snipText = ' ';

            if(currentCase.Snippet_Information__c != NULL){
                snipText += currentCase.Snippet_Information__c + '\n';
            }

            snipText += snippetIdMap.get(currentCase.Add_Snippet__c);
            currentCase.Snippet_Information__c = snipText;
        }


    }

    /**
     * beforeUpdate
     *
     * This method is called iteratively for each record to be updated during a BEFORE
     * trigger.
     */
    public void beforeUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject so){
        Case currentCase = (Case)so;
        Case oldCase = (Case)oldSo;

        // If the snippet lookup has changed and is not null, append the snippet text
        // to the snippet information textbox
        if(currentCase.Add_Snippet__c != NULL && currentCase.Add_Snippet__c != oldCase.Add_Snippet__c){
            String snipText = ' ';

            if(currentCase.Snippet_Information__c != NULL){
                snipText += currentCase.Snippet_Information__c + '\n';
            }

            snipText += snippetIdMap.get(currentCase.Add_Snippet__c);
            currentCase.Snippet_Information__c = snipText;
        }
    }

    /**
     * beforeDelete
     *
     * This method is called iteratively for each record to be deleted during a BEFORE
     * trigger.
     */
    public void beforeDelete(SObject so){}

    /**
     * afterInsert
     *
     * This method is called iteratively for each record inserted during an AFTER
     * trigger. Always put field validation in the 'After' methods in case another trigger
     * has modified any values. The record is 'read only' by this point.
     */
    public void afterInsert(SObject so){
        Case currentCase = (Case)so;

        if(currentCase.Origin == 'Phone'){
            Case_Call__c casecall = new Case_Call__c();

            casecall.Call_Subject__c = currentCase.Subject_Encrypted__c;
            casecall.Case_Reference__c = currentCase.Id;

            ccList.add(casecall);

        }

        if(currentCase.RecordTypeId == custReqRecType.Id
                && currentCase.Status == '01-New'
                && currentCase.Kinnser_closed_on_create__c == FALSE
                && currentCase.Email__c != NULL
                && currentCase.Do_Not_Send_Case_Email__c == FALSE){

            newCaseToEmail.add(currentCase);
        }

        if(currentCase.RecordTypeId == retradeReqRecType.Id
                //&& currentCase.Status == '01-New'
                && currentCase.Origin == 'Email'
                && currentCase.Kinnser_closed_on_create__c == FALSE
                && currentCase.Email__c != NULL
                && currentCase.Do_Not_Send_Case_Email__c == FALSE){

            newCaseToEmail.add(currentCase);
        }

    }

    public void afterUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject so){
        Case currentCase = (Case)so;
        Case oldCase = (Case)oldSo;

        if(currentCase.RecordTypeId == custReqRecType.Id
                && currentCase.Status == '90-Closed'
                && oldCase.Status != '90-Closed'
                && oldCase.Status != '40-Reopened'
                //&& currentCase.Kinnser_closed_on_create__c == FALSE
                && currentCase.Do_Not_Send_Case_Email__c == FALSE
                && currentCase.Email__c != NULL){

            closedCasesToEmail.add(currentCase);

            Kinnser_Email_Message__c kem = new Kinnser_Email_Message__c();

            kem.ToAddress__c = currentCase.Email__c;
            kem.Case__c = currentCase.Id;
            kem.Do_Not_Send__c = TRUE;
            kem.Incoming__c = FALSE;
            kem.ToName__c = currentCase.Calculated_Contact_Name__c;
            kem.Subject__c = 'Kinnser case resolved: ' + currentCase.CaseNumber;

            kem.TextBody__c = currentCase.Encrypted_Description__c;
            kem.TextBody__c += 'Dear ' + currentCase.Calculated_Contact_Name__c + '\n';
            kem.TextBody__c += 'Please note that your case ' + currentCase.CaseNumber +' has been resolved.\n';
            kem.TextBody__c += 'Resolution:'+ currentCase.Resolution_Summary__c +'\n';
            kem.TextBody__c += 'Please contact Kinnser Support if you continue to experience any difficulties or have any questions.';

            kemResolutions.add(kem);
        }

    }


    public void afterDelete(SObject so){}


    public void andFinally(){
        if(ccList.size()>0){
            insertCaseCalls(JSON.serialize(ccList));
        }

        if(closedCasesToEmail.Size() > 0){
            emailClosedCase(JSON.serialize(closedCasesToEmail));
        }

        if(newCaseToEmail.Size() > 0){
            emailNewCase(JSON.serialize(newCaseToEmail));
        }

        if(kemResolutions.Size() > 0){
            Insert kemResolutions;
        }

    }

    @future(callout=TRUE)
    public static void emailNewCase(String jsonNewCases){
        SendGridEmail seg = new SendGridEmail();
        seg.GenNewCase(jsonNewCases);

        seg.SendEmail();

    }

    @future(callout=TRUE)
    public static void emailClosedCase(String jsonClosedCases){
        SendGridEmail seg = new SendGridEmail();
        seg.GenCloseCase(jsonClosedCases);
        seg.SendEmail();

    }

    @future
    public static void insertCaseCalls(String jsonCaseCallList){
        List<Case_Call__c> caseCalls = (List<Case_Call__c>)JSON.deserialize(jsonCaseCallList, List<Case_Call__c>.class);
        if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
            Insert caseCalls;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm. Can you explain more about querying the field? Not sure if I am doing that or how to do it. I have permission to view, yes.

Comment: I posted the whole class above. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Since it is coming from a trigger context, it should be there.  So I'm leaning towards permission to the field?